# Local mirror auto repo sync from Remote repository

Tags: git, synchronization, mirror

I have a mirror branch MB made from Remote branch RB. 
Whenever a change gets merged to RB, i want MB to be synced automatically with changes merged to RB.
Should we do this using hooks?
is there any hook for post merge to RB?

If I do it in post-merge hook, should i add this post-merge hook to every git project? or should i add for complete repo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a classical job for a hook, yes, there's the `post-merge` hook, [as the official documentation tells you](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) and yes, you can simply modify the `post-commit` hook that you'll find in your `.git/hooks` directory.

Comment: Once some one pushes a code to git projects and it gets reviewed and finally the code is merged through gerrit -- will this post-merge gets invoked?

Comment: **Read the documentation I linked to.** The `git merge` command calls the hook, so the hook must be on the machine that does the merge, obviously.

Comment: yes. but once the git merge is done, how do I call a repo sync on my local branch? And should we restart the gerrit server after modifying the post-merge hook on my RB

Comment: The gerrit question is totally separate, ask it as a new question. Git doesn't "sync", git "push"es or "pull"s, so you'd probably want to `git push`; please read the git handbook intro.

Comment: yes , i need to push this git project changes to my local branch . How will the RB know about my MB. I want to know should i specify the complete force push command to MB in post merge hook of RB?

Comment: ask a separate question: Don't ask new questions in comments.

Comment: This is a related question for the same. If anybody knows a solution can help me

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using gerrit replication. 
https://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.0/config-replication.html use this link for more details